# Ajax function always returns false

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, asp.net-mvc-5

I have have web-service that checks whether a userName exists in the database or not, the service is working fine I checked, the problem is when I'm trying to call it using ajax function the result is always false which is in my case indicates that the user name is not in use and it is available...so this is my service code

```
[ScriptService]
public class RegisterationService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private SqlConnection con;
    //this function will call the sql procedure
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public string UserNameExist(string userName)
    {
        bool userNameInUse = false;
        Connection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("UserNameExists", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@UserName",
            Value = userName
        });

        con.Open();
        userNameInUse = Convert.ToBoolean(com.ExecuteScalar());

        Registeration reg = new Registeration();
        reg.UserName = userName;
        reg.UserNameInUse = userNameInUse;

        //to serialize this to JSON
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(reg));           
        con.Close();
        return js.Serialize(reg);
    }
    private void Connection()
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NerdsContext"].ToString();
        con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    }
}
```

and here is my ajax script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#txtUserName").keyup(function () {
                    var userNameVal = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
                    if (userNameVal.length >= 3)
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '../RegisterationService.asmx/UserNameExist',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            method: 'POST',
                            data: JSON.stringify({'userName': userNameVal}),
                            //the data the server expecting
                            dataType: 'json',

                            success: function (data) {
                                var divElement = $("#divOutput");
                                if (data.userNameInUse)
                                {
                                    divElement.css('color', 'red');
                                    divElement.text(userNameVal + ' is already in use');  

                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    divElement.css('color', 'green');
                                    divElement.text(userNameVal + ' is available');

                                }
                                //alert(data.userName);

                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                console.log(xhr.status);
                                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                                console.log(thrownError);
                            }


                        });
                    }
                });
});
```

I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
con.Close();
var obj = new Registration
{
    Username = userName,
    UserNameInUse = userNameInUse
};
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
```

Comment: Ok I already assigned the values to the  registration object, I really don't think this the answer, and i already checked the service it is working fine

Comment: Tell me what you are getting on `Inspect Element -> Network -> Response`

Comment: Nothing that is what makes it frustrating 
I don't know if it has anything to do with the problem but this is the output of my service
'<string>{"UserName":"salRad","UserNameInUse":true}</string>'

Comment: WebService is correct, just Show me a screen shot of that which data is came in your `Inspect Element -> Network -> Response`

Comment: WOW, ok I'm really new to this but thank you a lot I did what you told me and this is what came out
`"{"UserName":"salRad","UserNameInUse":true}"`
so what is the problem it came true but it was treated as false

Comment: Its all working fine brother. Everything is ohkay, I think you have front end mistake. You have to show me your UI.

Comment: I know the UI is fine but I tried viewing in another browser and I got this in my `Inspect Element -> Network -> Response`
`{"d":"{\"UserName\":\"salRad\",\"UserNameInUse\":true}"}`